# Why I get gap in table rows?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I work on my angularjs project.

I use ng-repeat to create rows in table.

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Weq1n10ku4V3pzHr9BV7?p=preview).

Here is html template:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="object in arr1 track by object.id">
            <td class="pull-left" ng-bind="object.name"></td>

            <td  ng-class="{'wrapper':showReview != $index }">
                <div ng-class="{'slide':showReview != $index}">

                    <a class=" btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="showReview = showReview == $index ? -1 : $index;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i></a>
                    <a class=" btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="showInspections = !showInspections; showReview = showReview == $index ? -1 : $index;"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></a>

                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="showInspections && showReview == $index">
          <td colspan="">
            {{t}}-{{$index}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.arr1 = [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'eee'},
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}];

  $scope.t=100;

});
```

Here how it looks in the view:

[image]

You can see in picture above I have gap between the rows and I cant figure out why I get this gap?

Comment: It's because you are floating the first columns to the left with your "pull-left" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one `th` in head and one `td` in second row you need to add `colspan="2"` on both of them.

Also do not use `class="pull-left"` with `td` take another element inside td and make it pull-left